# "POST" form data to XLS/CSV

Tags: html, excel, csv, offline

So I'm trying to essentially "POST" data from a form in an offline webpage, to an Excel spreadsheet, or CSV, or even just a TXT file. Now I have seen this to be possible using ActiveX in Internet Explorer, however, the methods I saw were pretty particular to the user's code, so I got a bit lost in translation being a beginner. Also some recommended using an offline database using JS, but I'm not sure where to begin with that.

Can anyone offer some insight on this? Is it possible? What would be the best route to take?

Comment: You could write a chrome plugin, then you can use something like https://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystem

Comment: If you need access to the local system and you can't write a plugin, you can't make this work on a webapp. By offline app, you mean there's no server involved? My suggestion is that you write a desktop app

Comment: To Juan's point, we really need to know if this application is to be ran locally on a client's machine, or from a server that clients access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to accomplish this. The best solution will be the one that suits your specific requirements. Obviously, creating a text/csv file is easier than creating an xls. That said, the basic psuedo code is as follows:

1. Collect form data
2. Create (in-memory or temporary) file from collected form data.
3. Return file as download to client, or just save to some location, OR (best option) insert a row into a database.

Comment: In regards to step 3, would there be a way to actually write to the existing file without hassling the end-user to download each time?

For instance, each submit would essentially just create a new line in the file.

Comment: Sure, you'd just be overwriting the file each time by saving it to the same location.

Comment: @Didaxis The user would still have to download the file each time

Comment: @Juan Mendez There's nothing preventing a web application from saving to a location on the file system...

Comment: @Didaxis Show us some code that will let you write to the client's file system

Comment: @JuanMendes, he/she said this application was "offline" and didn't specify if it is being ran locally. Hence Step 3 of my answer which offers both possibilities as solutions... not to mention in many corporate environments we use networked/shared folders

Comment: "Each 'Submit' would write a new line" is the main kicker here. If I can't do that, I'd have to restructure the entire project before moving forward at all. Any ideas, guys?

Comment: @Didaxis I do have access to a networked/shared folder on my corporate network if needed. Would that make much of a difference versus an offline folder?

Comment: @Autonomous, if that suits your user's requirements, sure, it's a viable option. But that also means your application runs with the necessary credentials to access the share. IMO, returning a download to the client is better, unless there's a good reason it must be written to the same location each time

Comment: Without a server, you can't even cause a file download

Comment: Juan, your local machine can serve requests to your local machine, no?

Comment: @Didaxis the form is being used to allow my technicians to document incidents faster, so causing a download is inconvenient and defeats the premise. That's why I'd like for it to write to a new line instead.

As far as any accesses, file shares, or back-end setup, I can accomplish that. The code is the main focus as of now.

Comment: @Autonomous, See my edit to Step 3. By far, this sounds like your best option.

Comment: @Didaxis If you have a server on your local machine, yes you can. The server is just going to write to file system.

Comment: @didaxis Okay, that sounds viable, but out of curiosity, what's to say you can't emulate a database with an xls?

Comment: @Autonomous, an XLS certainly could suit your needs. But a database is made for this sort of thing. Let's say at a later time, your technicians want to be able to see these incidents on a web page, and track how they've been handled, and update incidents, etc. That will be mighty tough using an excel spreadsheet in this manner

Comment: @Jaun, if I can serve requests from my local machine, I can certianly return a download to myself, in which case the browser becomes the application responsible for writing to the file system, not my server. It is no different than if the server is my own machine, or a box 1000 miles away

Comment: @Didaxis but what you are saying, is I COULD absolutely use an XLS? This would be best as a temporary solution so I can get this project moving without waiting for approvals.

My next question would be how I would POST the form data to the DB/XLS without using PHP. Would AJAX work fine offline?

Comment: @Autonomous, AJAX is not a programming language, it's a way of making requests to a server using XML or JSON in more modern times. Maybe there is an ActiveX control that allows you to do this, but it's non-standard, and is platform dependent. Again, a database is a better solution. I offer you this advice, even if it's outside your comfort zone, take the time today/tonight and learn how to do this using PHP (or whatever your server side lang is) writing to a database. This is the basis for most web applications. It's worth your while to learn this stuff

Comment: @Didaxis I know PHP, and this would be remarkably simple ..but PHP is serverside, so that wouldn't be viable. Its not a matter of comfort zone, its a matter of not wanting to wait 1 year+ for Novo Nordisk to approve anything else. I need it to be as standalone as possible.